# Laravel many-to-many relationship query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I am building a Laravel application with a users table and an activities table, and a many-to-many relationship between activities and users implemented with a pivot table called assignments:

- users: id, ...
- activities: id, ...
- assignments: id, activity_id, user_id, ...

I need to keep a record of each time a user completes an activity. A user can complete the same activity many times. I am trying to decide on the best way to model this in the database. The options as far as I can see are:

1. a table completions: id, assignment_id, ...
2. a second pivot table completions: id, activity_id, user_id, ...

I can create the migrations etc. However I am struggling with the Model classes and their relationship methods. In particular, for the first option above, how would I define the required Model classes and relationship methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have pretty much everything sorted except the activity tracking. So, here's what I propose:

> users table

with columns id, name, email, etc

> activities table

with columns id, name, etc

> user_activity table (pivot)

with columns id, user_id, activity_id, etc
This table will contain the many to many mapping between users and activities.

> activity_tracking

with columns id, user_activity_id, status, updated_at etc
Here you could use an integer value for status to signify completion lets say 1. And using updated_at and created_at you could track activity start and completion timing.

Answer (score 0):

create `activity_user` table and just add `activity_id` and `user_id`. id column unnecessary for this. Then add this codes to User Model:

```
public function activity()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Activity', 'activity_user', 'user_id', 'activity_id');
}
```

If i understand correctly, there is no need anything else.