# How to use belongsToMany with multiple models in Nova

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I am trying to attach multiple models to a pivot table in Laravel Nova.

```
// Post model
public function awards()
{
return $this->belongsToMany(Award::class, 'user_post_awards')
            ->withTimestamps();
}

// User model
public function awards()
{
return $this->belongsToMany(Award::class, 'user_post_awards')
            ->withTimestamps();
}

// Award model
public function users()
{
return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_post_awards')
            ->withTimestamps();
}

public function posts()
{
return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'user_post_awards')
            ->withTimestamps();
}

// Nova resource
public function fields(Request $request)
{
return [
    Text::make('name')->sortable(),
    belongsToMany::make('Users', 'users', 'App\Nova\User'),
    belongsToMany::make('Posts', 'posts', 'App\Nova\Post'),
];
}
```

In my pivot table user_post_awards the user_id is required. So when i try to attach a Post i get an error. So the question is how can i set the user_id when attaching a Post to the Award model in Laravel Nova? Is there maybe a way to overwrite the attach function in Nova?

Edit: I am looking for a way to add a user_id to the pivot table when i am attaching a Post to an award.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel many-to-many relationship query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50487508/laravel-many-to-many-relationship-query)

Answer (score 1):

I solved your problem by create a model and resource for the pivot table.Case you want to create a tri-relations, you can open the pivot resource, then select each values and attach. Case you want to detach the relation, you can choose detach from each model, or from pivot resource!

Reference my codes below, happy coding! Notes: The name of pivot table “award_post_user” I name it from Laravel convention. You can read it [here](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices).

```
// database\migrations\2019_07_30_000133_create_posts_table.php
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('title',500);
        });
    }

// database\migrations\2019_07_30_000243_create_awards_table.php
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('awards', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('name',100);
        });
    }

// database\migrations\2019_07_30_000741_create_award_post_user_table.php
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('award_post_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('post_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->bigInteger('award_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

// app\User.php
    public function awards()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Award::class,'award_post_user');
    }

// app\Post.php
    public function awards()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Award::class,'award_post_user');
    }

// app\Award.php
class Award extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class,'award_post_user');
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'award_post_user');
    }
}

// app\AwardPostUser.php
class AwardPostUser extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'award_post_user';
}

// app\Nova\User.php
    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make()->sortable(),
            ...
            BelongsToMany::make('Awards'),
        ];
    }

// app\Nova\Post.php
    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make()->sortable(),
            Text::make('Title'),
            BelongsToMany::make('Awards')
        ];
    }

// app\Nova\Award.php
    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make()->sortable(),
            Text::make('Name'),
            BelongsToMany::make('Posts','posts',\App\Nova\Post::class),
            BelongsToMany::make('Users','users',\App\Nova\User::class),
        ];
    }

// app\Nova\AwardPostUser.php
    public static $model = 'App\AwardPostUser';

    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make()->sortable(),

            Select::make('User','user_id')
            ->options(\App\User::pluck('name','id')->toArray())
            ->displayUsingLabels(),

            Select::make('Post','post_id')
            ->options(\App\Post::pluck('title','id')->toArray())
            ->displayUsingLabels(),

            Select::make('Award','award_id')
            ->options(\App\Award::pluck('name','id')->toArray())
            ->displayUsingLabels(),
        ];
    }


  [1]: https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices
```